# Resize an image in HTML without JavaScript

Tags: html, image, resize

I have used media queries to resize a picture on different breakpoints,
i don't want to use JS for the resize and wanted to have everything in html since i want to use craft as a CMS on the website and want to have dynamicly generated code , i have been reading tons of sites and blogs and they all start to confuse me more and more ..is it really a clever solution to use the picture tag like this :

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/news.jpg" media="(min-width: 1429px)">
  <source srcset="img/news_m.jpg" media="(min-width: 960px)">
  <source srcset="img/news.jpg" media="(min-width: 460px)">
  <img srcset="img/news_m.jpg"/>
</picture>
```

i couldn't figure out the the img way ( setsrc with w etc) it never really worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using picturefill as a fallback ..it works fine ..if anyone was wondering :-) thanks guys

https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/

```
<picture>
  <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
  <source srcset="img/news.jpg" media="(min-width: 1429px)">
  <source srcset="img/news_m.jpg" media="(min-width: 960px)">
  <source srcset="img/news.jpg" media="(min-width: 460px)">
  <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
  <img srcset="img/news_m.jpg" alt="My default image">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML with CSS you would do something like:

`<img src="img/news.jpg" style="min-width:1429px;" />`

You should read up about HTML and CSS if you want to do web development.

Comment: It all works, I have just been wondering if it's OK with the picture tag way. I was referencing to articles like this one : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/responsive-images-done-right-guide-picture-srcset/

Comment: I wasn't up to speed about the picture tag. It seems like it's meant to be the way forward, so yes you can. I usually check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) with new web technologies to see which browsers support them and how likely they are to change. When it hasn't become standard yet, it's always possible that it changes or gets removed, in which case you will have to change your code as well.